# What are advantages and disadvantages of using gettext vs a separate dynamic library for each locale?

Tags: localization, translation, gettext

I had a discussion with another SO user about [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) and its limitations among other things. He argued that gettext is "deficient" and not suitable for idiomatic output in other languages and the proper way to do this is to "write a separate DLL/class for each locale." I thought this deserves a separate question, so what are the advantages and disadvantages of using gettext vs a separate dynamic library for each locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly don't see what a separate dynamic library would do?

The problem with localization normally does not lie with gettext, but much more with the implementation and with the translation.

E.g. if you have text like this: "I have " + i + " cars" then a good translation is difficult.
 But that is not a gettext issue.

Comment: Answering your question about the dynamic library, as far as I understood, one would create a variation of the source code for each language/locale with translated strings, etc. and compile it into separate dynamic libraries selected depending on the current locale. Personally I see it as a maintenance burden and don't see any advantages.

Comment: That sounds like a nightmare if you ask me. I work in a translation agency and I have not seen this in my 6 years of work.

Comment: I work at an agency. We only develop tools for inhouse and their are with .NET. But from experience gettext is pretty powerful. Also supports multiple pluralforms.